# Spring Batch read XML with local DTD using StaxEventItemReader / Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: xml, spring, xml-parsing, spring-batch, dtd

Configuration for `ItemReader` in Spring Batch as follows:

```
@Bean public StaxEventItemReader<Foo> fooXmlReader() {
    final StaxEventItemReader<Foo> itemReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("/my/foo/file.xml"));
    itemReader.setFragmentRootElementName("Foo");
    itemReader.setUnmarshaller(fooUnmarshaller());
    itemReader.setStrict(false);

    return itemReader;
}

@Bean public Jaxb2Marshaller fooUnmarshaller() {
    final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("org.group.jobs.foo.jaxb");
    marshaller.setMappedClass(Foo.class);

    return marshaller;
}
```

The `file.xml` looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE Bar SYSTEM "Bar.dtd">
<Bar>
 <TS>20170531220004000</TS>
 <Foo>
  <Bla>10101</Bla>
 </Foo>
 <Foo>
  <Bla>10111</Bla>
 </Foo>
</Bar>
```

The `Bar.dtd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!ELEMENT Bar (TS, Foo+)>
<!ELEMENT TS (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Foo (Bla)>
<!ELEMENT Bla (#PCDATA)>
```

When starting the project and things get up, injected and initialized, I get the following exception:

```
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: (was java.io.FileNotFoundException) C:\projects\apps\myproject\Bar.dtd (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,63]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:630)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:461)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader.findDtdExtSubset(ValidatingStreamReader.java:475)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.ValidatingStreamReader.finishDTD(ValidatingStreamReader.java:358)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.finishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3737)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2082)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1069)
    at com.ctc.wstx.evt.WstxEventReader.peek(WstxEventReader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.stax.DefaultFragmentEventReader.peek(DefaultFragmentEventReader.java:173)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.moveCursorToNextFragment(StaxEventItemReader.java:151)
```

Obviously the DTD file is not found. Normally I would write a `EntityResolver` for this purpose. But I don't know where to configure it in the `StaxEventItemReader` or `Jaxb2Marshaller`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would start by enabling DTD support (it's off by default): https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/oxm/jaxb/Jaxb2Marshaller.html

Comment: Hi Miachel, thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately I get the same exception when setting `supportDtd` to `true`.